# Lorentzian manifolds of negative spacelike sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a simply connected Lorentzian manifold of signature $(-,+,\ldots,+)$ and such that the sectional curvature of any space-like surface is non-positive. Is it true that there are no conjugate points or cut points along space-like geodesics?

Comment: I think you may want to add the hypothesis that $M$ be simply connected, because there are simple examples in which there are cut points:  If you let $M = \mathbb{R}\times S$ with metric $g = -\mathrm{d}t^2 + g_0$ where $(S,g_0)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold with negative sectional curvature, this satisfies your curvature hypothesis, but there are clearly cut points for the geodesics in $\{0\}\times S$.  Also, certain discrete quotients of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ endowed with its usual bi-invariant Lorentzian metric (of type (-,+,+)$ give such examples.

Comment: Yes that’s a great suggestion. I was thinking of adding this assumption as well.